# Jekyll commands doesn't work in Html documents

Tags: web, jekyll, jekyll-paginator

I'm a beginner and I'm trying to use Jekyll. I watch some tutorials, I did all steps,  I installed and created the project but when I try to use the jekyll, it's doesn't work.

I try to call the layout from  the folder "_layouts" but when I open my browser it's like an string, it's happen in includes and layout import.

I don't know what is  wrong.

Comment: Here's a good video tutorial on using layouts: http://jekyll.tips/jekyll-casts/layouts/. You're going to need to elaborate and provide some code and/or a repo URL in order for someone to help on a specific problem.